# Migrate from template_file to templatefile

Tags: terraform

Apparently, template_file was deprecated, and I need to migrate to `templatefile`

I have the following YAML that needs to be populated with two variables

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = file("cloud-init.yaml")

  vars = {
    user = var.USER
    tskey = var.TAILSCALE_AUTHKEY
  }
}
```

Used below

```
user_data = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
```

How to do this in a new way, using templatefile?

EDIT: Full source code https://github.com/skhaz/my-cloud-workspace

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you looked at the documentation at all? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile This website isn't a free code conversion service. Please show your effort and explain in detail where you are stuck.

Comment: You haven't provided your template file, nor you haven't explained what's wrong with your current attempt?

Comment: @Marcin I have updated the question. The problem is that the method that I was using to populate some variables on the template were depreciated, and doesn’t work on ARM

Answer (score 7):

These days you should use [templatefile](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile), not `template_file`. In your case you could do:

```
locals {
  user_data = templatefile("cloud-init.yaml", {
    user = var.USER
    tskey = var.TAILSCALE_AUTHKEY
  })
}
```

then

```
user_data = local.user_data
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a separate .yml file
Then call the template .yml file through:

> user_data = file("filename.yml")

Comment: And how can I apply the variables?